# prove $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the same number of roots in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, finite-fields

Suppose $p$ is a prime,and $f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{p-1}k!x^{k}$, $g(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{p-1}\frac{1}{k!}x^{k}$,prove $f,g$ have the same number of roots in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$

I tried to consider the relation between $f(x)$ and $g(1/x)$, but I do not know what should I do next.Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Z}[p]$? The notation usually means "least ring that contains both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $p$", but that's just $\mathbb{Z}$. Did you mean the intergers modulo $p$, $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (or $\mathbb{F}_p$, or $GF(p)$, or $\mathbb{Z}_p$ though the latter can be confused with the $p$-adic integers...)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin it is $\mathbb{Z}\backslash p\mathbb{Z}$,I will edit it

Comment: If you mean the finite field with $p$ elements, then it is usually denoted by $\Bbb F_p$. What are $k!$ and $1/k!$ in $\Bbb F_p$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think k! is k! mod(p) here and $\frac{1}{k!}$ is the inverse of $k!$ in the finite field

Comment: Have you gone through the explicit examples $p=2,3,5$? That's what I would do ...

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I tried but couldn’t see how to get a general proof

Comment: Maybe at least write those down. Since $p=2$ is trivial, maybe the ones for $3,5,7$ with their respective roots. This way you show some work, and maybe someone sees a pattern.

Comment: I wonder if it might be helpful to observe $\frac{1}{(p-1)!} = -1$, $\frac{1}{(p-2)!} = (-1) \cdot \frac{1}{(p-1)!} = 1$, $\frac{1}{(p-3)!} = (-1)(-2)\cdot \frac{1}{(p-1)!} = -2$, etc. (all in $\mathbb{F}_p$ of course).

Comment: @DanielSchepler Wow that seems to work,thank you! I will try  $g(-1/x)$ to cancel the minus sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an application of [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) and [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem). The first states that $p$ is prime if and only if

$$(p-1)!\equiv -1 (\text{mod}\ p)$$

This gives us that for $0\leq k<p$ we have

$$(p-1)!=k!(p-1)(p-2)...(k+1)\equiv -1(\text{mod}\ p)$$

$$\Rightarrow k!\equiv -[(p-1)(p-2)...(k+1)]^{-1}(\text{mod}\ p)$$

$$\Rightarrow (k!)^{-1}\equiv -(p-1)(p-2)...(k+1)$$
$$=-(-1)(-2)...(-p+k+1)=(-1)^{k+1}(p-1-k)!(\text{mod}\ p)$$

This implies that if $r\equiv x^{-1}(\text{mod}\ p)$ then

$$g(-r)=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}(k!)^{-1}(-r)^{k}\equiv-\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}(p-1-k)!r^k(\text{mod}\ p)$$

Then using [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) we know

$$r^k\equiv x^{-k}\equiv x^{p-1-k}(\text{mod}\ p)$$

This implies

$$-\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}(p-1-k)!r^k\equiv-\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}(p-1-k)!x^{p-1-k}=-\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}k!x^k=-f(x)(\text{mod}\ p)$$

Thus $f(x)\equiv-g(r)\ (\text{mod }p)$. Since $f(0)\neq 0\neq g(0)$ we are assured that the roots inverses exist.

Comment: Actually $f(x) = -x^{p-1}g(-\frac{1}{x})$, right?

Comment: $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\ (\text{mod }p)$ by Fermat's Little Theorem. But I guess thats not strictly necessary for this proof